# Python requests with proxy results in SSLError WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, python-requests

I can't use the different proxy in Python.

My code:

```
import requests

proxies = {
    "https":'https://154.16.202.22:3128',
    "http":'http://154.16.202.22:3128'
    }

r=requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies)
print(r.json())
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
.
.
.
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  .
  .
  .
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

I executed `pip install requests`.

I executed `pip uninstall pyopenssl`, then tried to `pip install` an old version of of pyopenssl but it didn't work.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proxy you use simply does not support proxying `https://` URLs:

```
$ https_proxy=http://154.16.202.22:3128 curl -v https://httpbin.org/ip
*   Trying 154.16.202.22...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to (nil) (154.16.202.22) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to httpbin.org:443
> CONNECT httpbin.org:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: httpbin.org:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Apart from that the URL for the proxy itself is wrong - it should be `http://..` and not `https://..` even if you proxy HTTPS traffic. But requests actually ignores the given protocol completely, so this error is not the reason for the problem.  But just to demonstrate that it would not work either if the proxy itself got accessed with HTTPS (as the URL suggests):

```
$ https_proxy=https://154.16.202.22:3128 curl -v https://httpbin.org/ip
*   Trying 154.16.202.22...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to (nil) (154.16.202.22) port 3128 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

So the fix here would be to use a different proxy, one which actually supports proxying `https://` URLs.

Comment: thanks for your answer Steffen. You say we should use a different proxy but how do we know which one to use?

Comment: @Scinana: *"how do we know which one to use?... "* - You cannot expect an arbitrary free proxy you happen to find on the internet to work for you. Depending on what you want to do you can setup your own proxy, use paid services ...

Comment: The apache (actually libssl) error message:

AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
Library Error: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number

is one of the most misleading error messages ever. Do not start with debugging SSL/ TLS protocol versions. Always check first if we are talking to a plain unencrypted HTTP port.

Answer (score 23):

Issue happens due to bug in latest urllib3(I've spotted it in version `1.26.3`). Try downgrading to `1.23` via `pip3 install urllib3==1.23`, it should fix the problem.

Comment: This answer helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any more information on this being a bug (issue link, etc)? There were some proxy changes in a recent release, and I'm trying to determine if it's a bug or the use of it needs to change - https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1923

Comment: This issue may be worth checking out - https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2075

Comment: If I understand this correctly, previous versions of urllib3 seemed to paper over incorrect use. With newer versions, incorrect use no longer works. Per my previous comment, the following may be helpful (was for me): https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2075

Comment: The most recent working version can be installed like so:
`pip install urllib3==1.25.11`

Comment: Thanks a lot, would've never figured this one out myself!

Comment: While this maybe have originally been the truth, the bug has been fixed; anything nowadays means that the proxy you are using is not working correctly and needs to be addressed.

Comment: urllib3==1.25.11 works for me, but urllib3==1.23 didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Seems to be a bug at recent versions of `requests` library.

I fixed by replacing the `https` by `http` at the handler dictionary, for https protocol.

For example: if the proxy is http**s**, then declare it like this (without the S in the proxy IP:

`"https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080"`

Example:

```
import requests

proxies = {"http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
           "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080"}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```