# SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER ON PYTHON REQUEST

Tags: python, debugging, web, python-requests, ssl-certificate

Python version: 3.9.1

I trying to write bot that send requests and it work perfectly fine, the only issue that i have is when i trying to use web debugging programs such as Charles 4.6.1 or Fiddler Everywhere. When I open it to see bot traffic and response form server it crash showing me this error:

```
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1124)')))
```

I used to have this issue and I was able to fix it by simply adding `verify=False` to my request, but right now it does not work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It's a bug in urllib3.  You have to specify your proxy in the request, and change the 'https' value to 'http'.

My example:

```
proxies = {'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'}
request = r.get('https://www.example.net', verify=False, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Not verifying the https connection is not a solution, but an insecure hack.

Comment: @atlau is that turning of verification to the end server, or just to the proxy, though?  Disabling verification of a server running on localost is pretty safe, IMO.

Answer (score 17):

Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66656188/10536858).

In short you should downgrade urllib:

```
pip3 install urllib3==1.23
```

Comment: There is compatibility issue with the newer python version

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else is having this issue in 2023, simply updating the urllib3 library worked for me.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade urllib3
```

Comment: `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
botocore 1.31.65 requires urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4; python_version < "3.10", but you have urllib3 2.0.7 which is incompatible.`

Comment: this time another error occured:"'cannot import name \'appengine\' from \'urllib3.contrib\'"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but i solved it by changing the "https" in the URL to "http":

Example:

```
ulr_example = 'https://example.com'
```

to

```
url_example = 'http://example.com'
```

Comment: That's what Bryan Hamilton wrote up there